# How to abstract out datasource selection in a DRYish way using GORM

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a domain set up with n datasources (we will call it 2 here). I currently have to access the objects for finds etc this way...

```
// DS1
Item.find(id)
// DS2
Item.ds2.find(id);
```

This works ok on a small logical function but when there are a alot of finds and saves it makes a very un-DRY environment...

```
if(isDs1){
  Item.find(id)
  ...
}
else{
  Item.ds.find(id)
  ...
}
```

I was thinking something like this in JS...

```
String ds = isDs1 ? 'ds1' : 'ds2'
Item[ds].find(id)
```

But this isn't possible in Groovy(?)

This there another way to do this in a fairly DRY way?

**Update**

for those that are confused my DataSource.groovy would look like this...

```
environments {
  development {
    datasource_ds1{
      ...
    }
    datasource_ds2{
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the content (or the mock of item). You can query the data with. 'executeQuery', findBy , FindAllBy, etc. The approach you're using to solve your problem might be what is making it harder. Why do you use ```
Item.find(id)
And after that a Item.ds.find(id) ? ``` **Item.ds** is a node too ? Please expand the description of your problem. :]

Comment: Have you ever worked with multiple data sources configured in your Datasources.groovy? I will edit but this is a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy has support for dynamic invocation. The equivalent to your javascript example would be something like this:

```
String ds = isDs1 ? 'ds1' : 'ds2'
Item."${ds}".find(id)
```

Comment: Yup that looks like a winner I will try it out and confirm. I knew there was some corner of groovy I was missing. Would you also say this is the most effective way using GORM?